# How to properly delete a file in .Net Core with C# from a folder with large amount of other files or folders

Tags: c#, .net, file, .net-core

I am removing files in a loop with [File.Delete(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netframework-4.8) in a simplest .Net Core Console application:

```
1. foreach (var listing in listings)
2.    File.Delete(listing.Path);
```

**BUT** the issue is that the application randomly hangs on line 2, **no exception is thrown**. After application restart, several files are removed successfully and the app randomly hangs, again, on another file.

There are some items to note:

- `listing.Path` is an absolute path to a file on a disk
- `listing.Path` looks like `D:\Output\00000001\6b1c8e6c-7d83-481a-a7db-aac9024059c4.png`
- the length of `listings` **array** is about **10** items
- file **DOES** exist in every case
- Storage: **Seagate Exos 7E8 512E 8TB 7200rpm 256MB ST8000NM000A 3.5" SATA III** HDD
- OS: Windows 10 64x
- total size of `Output` folder is **210GB**
- `Output` folder contains **137 000** other folders with **928 000** files in total (approximately **5 - 10** files per folder)
- average file size is about **350KB**

I suspect that issue is somehow related to the amount of files. But `File.Delete` should be the most **reliable** way to remove a file, and it just hangs without any response for multiple hours. Which forces me to kill the process of the app. **Is there a better or more efficient way to remove a file?**

**Update:** After moving all the files to another Windows machine in a network with an **SSD** installed and executing the application there it worked perfectly fine. So it may look like a hardware issue. Therefore I will rephrase the question title from **How to properly delete a file in .Net Core with C#** to **How to properly delete a file in .Net Core with C# from a folder with large amount of other files or folders**

Comment: So "multiple hours" so that shoot my first thought that it was a big file and you didn't give it enough time.  Is there any chance another process is still using the file?  It might be waiting for some process to close it . . . or worse yet some zombie process has it open and will never release it.  Check for hung processes?

Comment: Just to be clear, listings is definitely an array, not some kind of lazy enumerator?

Comment: @FrankMerrow, if file is used by another process I should've just got an exception? ... And file is deleted after I kill and restart the app. It just hangs on the other file then

Comment: @MikeZboray, yes it is an **array**

Comment: Does this happen on a specific file or random one?

Comment: During the deletion process, maybe new files are created in the same folder?

Comment: I'll suggest to change to another computer and check if it's a hardware or OS related.

Comment: I nosed around and Microsoft has a tool you can download called "Process Explorer".  A quick review of the download page indicates it will show you what processes have a handle to a given file.  Worth a shot.  I agree you "should" get an exception, but if a zombie process has it . . . hard telling what might happen.

Comment: Are you needing to only delete *some* files in the directory structure, but leave others? If not, why not just do a recursive [`Directory.Delete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete)?

Comment: @LouisGo, random file every time. I've switched to another machine with an ssd and currently the app runs flawlessly. So it may be a hardware issue ...

Comment: @MarioVernari, no new files are created in the folder when I am running my app

Comment: @Herohtar yes, I need to delete a specific file. I have ~10 files in a folder, and have an array of ~5 listings (among those 10) to be removed. Directory.Delete() is not an option for my case.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't expect to create an array with hundreds of thousands of filenames and then loop through them deleting them very fast

2) The file system, especially if the directory is on a network share, mapped drive, or in use by another application will be slow and block operations.  For example, a processing adding new files to a directory as fast as possible will conflict and possibly deadlock with one deleting files as fast as possible from the same directory.

3) Files may be locked by another process

Try some tests
a) How long does it take to get a list of all of the files to be deleted?
b) How long does it take to delete 1000 files in a row?

One queue system I developed had large numbers of files with multiple processes creating files, multiple processes processing files and then deleting the files.

We had 3 directories: Inbound, BeingProcessed, and ForDeletion

Each new file was put in the Inbound directory
Another process would move the file from the inbound directory to the BeingProcessed directory, open and lock the file, then process the file and the move the file to the ForDeletion directory
Another process would delete files in the ForDeletion directory